# como criar um histograma de frequência com intervalos não uniforme predefinidos?

Tags: r

Como posso fazer um histograma no Rstudio com a frequência no eixo y e no eixo x intervalos pré-definidos não uniformes, por exemplo: 0-50, 50-150, 150-500, 500-2000.

tenho um data.frame hipotético, pois nao gostaria de compartilhar meus dados originais.

```
dados <- c(1,1.2,40,1000,36.66,400.55,100,99,2,1500,333.45,25,125.66,141,5,87,123.2,61,93,85,40,205,208.9).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, basta usar o argumento `breaks` personalizado. Por exemplo, usando o `R` padrão:

```
dados <- c(1, 1.2, 40, 1000, 36.66, 400.55, 100, 99, 2, 1500, 333.45, 
  25, 125.66, 141, 5, 87, 123.2, 61, 93, 85, 40, 205, 208.9)

hist(dados, breaks = c(0, 50, 150, 500, 2000), freq = TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- as.data.frame(dados)

ggplot(dados, aes(x = dados)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = c(0, 50, 150, 500, 2000))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sua ideia foi bem boa, mas como faço para ele ficar com as barras de tamanho igual, mas intervalo personalizado?

Comment: Como assim? O que é "tamanho"? É a largura da barra? E se for a largura da barra, como elas poderiam ficar iguais se os intervalos tem tamanhos diferentes?

Comment: Isso como as barras ficariam iguais considerando que os intervalos são iguais.

Comment: Esse comentário não faz sentido. Continuo sem entender como meu gráfico poderia ser diferente, considerando o que foi pedido na pergunta original.

Comment: é que eu achava que poderia fazer uma grafico onde as barras teriam a mesma largura, porém com intervalos no eixo x diferentes. seria possível?

Comment: Possível é, mas não será um histograma. Histogramas são gráficos de distribuição de frequencia, a área (altura e largura) deve ser proporcional aos dados.

Comment: entendi Carlos, como eu poderia fazer isso, pois gostaria de saber a frequência que um determinado valor se encontra dentro de um determinado valor, acho que estou meio perdido para um gráfico tao simples rsrsrs.